# How would I do a template (like in C++) for setting shader uniforms in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I've been learning Rust recently and am working on a 3d engine using glfw3 and gl. I've got as far as trying to get a shader program that worked in my C++ engine working on my Rust one but have hit a snag on the implementation of setting shader uniforms.

shader.h:

```cpp
template <typename T> void SetUniform(const GLchar* name, const T& data);
```

shader.cpp

```cpp
template <> void ShaderProgram::SetUniform<int>(const GLchar* name, const int& data) {
    glUniform1i(GetUniformLocation(name), data);
}

template <> void ShaderProgram::SetUniform<float>(const GLchar* name, const float& data) {
    glUniform1f(GetUniformLocation(name), data);
}

template <> void ShaderProgram::SetUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec2& data) {
    glUniform2f(GetUniformLocation(name), data.x, data.y);
}
//etc...
```

With my limited knowledge of Rust, I tried using a match statement, as it has so far saved me a lot of hassle, to no avail.

```
pub fn set_uniform<T>(&mut self, value: T){
    match T {
        u32 => {/*insert gl call here*/},
        f32 => {/*insert gl call here*/},
        //etc...
        _ => {panic!()}
    }
}
```

I also came across traits, but had no luck trying to tweak them to do what I needed. I'd hoped it would have been something like this although I understand the syntax is very wonky.

```
trait SetUniform<T, Self = ShaderProgram> {
    fn set_uniform(self: &mut Self, value: T)
    where
        T: Sized;
}
```

Is there any way to do this with just one function name that can take in any type of parameter or should I just give in and make a bunch of differently named set_uniform functions for each different type?

Comment: The intent behind traits is to not "branch" within each implementation, but instead to have separate implementations. You can make a trait `X` which has specific functions (unimplemented) and then `impl X<Y>` for a given `Y`. In your case it's likely `impl SetUniform<u32> for ...`

Comment: `match` works on values, not types, so you'll never be able to use it for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done with traits.

What changes is the type of `value` so we need a trait that we can implement on those types, `i32`, `f32`, etc. This could look something like this:

```rust
trait SetUniform {
    fn set_uniform(location: GLint, value: Self);
}
```

(I'm assuming that the `glUniform` functions all have a signature like `fn(GLint, ...)` or similar)

Now we implement it for our argument types:

```rust
impl SetUniform for f32 {
    fn set_uniform(location: GLint, value: Self) {
        glUniform1f(location, value)
    }
}

impl SetUniform for i32 {
    fn set_uniform(location: GLint, value: Self) {
        glUniform1i(location, value)
    }
}

// guessing the types here, but the principle should be clear
impl SetUniform for &Vec2 {
    fn set_uniform(location: GLint, value: Self) {
        glUniform2f(location, value.x, value.y)
    }
}

// etc for other types
```

Then your calling function (simplified for this illustration) can look like this:

```rust
fn set_uniform<T: SetUniform>(location: GLint, value: T) {
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `T` is now bound on the `SetUniform` trait...
    SetUniform::set_uniform(location, value)
    //                                ^^^^^ ... which is why this works
}
```

Comment: Small note: idiomatically, `set_uniform` would take `self` as first parameter. It would simplify the call location to: `value.set_uniform(location);`

Comment: @MatthieuM. I guess. I picked this signature to be consistent with the `glUniform*` family of functions. Conciseness didn't really strike me as that important because the associated trait function would only be called directly once from the wrapper function.

Comment: My point was, if you can call `value.set_uniform(location)`, you don't even _need_ the wrapper function :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Right. I just felt that `value.set_uniform(location)` reads strangely because the parameters look swapped (I want to uniformly set a location to a value not the other way around), but that may just be me. In any case, it's a good addition :)

Comment: That's a valid point. If you want `location.set_uniform(value)` instead, you can create a trait `trait SetUniform<T> { fn set_uniform(&self, value: T); }` and then implement `SetUniform<u32>`, `SetUniform<i32>`, etc... for `GLint`. It works both ways.